# Setting an instance variable to an instance of the class itself

Tags: java, variables, this, instance

I didn't know how to phrase this question, and I'm not asking for help, I'm just curious as to why this is possible.

Say I have a class foo:

```
public class foo {

    private foo i = this;

    public foo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why am I able to set `i` to an instance of the class itself?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to do so? `i` is a variable of type `foo`, this means that it can hold a reference to an object of the same type. `this` is an object of type `foo`, so you can assign it to `i`.

Comment: `i` and `this` are just references (much like pointers in languages like C++), i.e. they will "point" to the same instance. Nothing odd here.

Comment: How would a Singleton be implemented if `getInstance()` couldn't return an instance of the class itself?

Comment: the foo in `foo i` is just a type. (please name your class accordingly, with `Foo`). You can have a class pointing to an(other) instance of the same class.

Comment: Maybe are you asking in relation to the execution of the constructor?

Comment: I think it was weird to me that a class could reference itself in a variable, rather than it being referenced outside the class like normal. I'm just figuring out the quirks of Java at this point, thanks.

Comment: @deHaar [Like this](https://ideone.com/p1dDH2) ?

Comment: @Michael `static`, sure… But it is still some kind of class attribute, isn't it?

Comment: @deHaar From my comprehension, OP is only confused as to why an *instance* might want to store a reference to itself as a field. The example you've given does not prove that it's necessary to allow such behaviour, as I've demonstrated.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, I'm relatively new to Java and I didn't see the use in a class storing a reference to itself, when other classes would usually be using instances of it instead.

Comment: @Michael ok, you're right then…

Comment: @ddlkkd we have only one object in heap and `this` and `i` both refers to it. You can see my answer below for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see what would happen when an object of `foo` is created.

```
foo x = new foo();
```

On encountring `new` JVM will create an object of `foo` in heap. Next step (Note its Next step) is constructor execution. In java object is created on heap and then constructor is invoked. This is the reason even if constructor throws an exception, even then object is created (can be reclaimed in finalize()).  As object is already created and is present in heap *references* can refer to it. 
`this` is reference to the object.

Now `private foo i = this;` is executed as a part of constructor (this is as per java behavior, all instance fields if initialized at the place of declaration, it is executed whenever constructor is invoked).  `this` already refers to the object created on heap and now `i` also refers to the same Object on Heap. Once constructor is successfully executed without any exception the variable `x` also refers to the same Object on heap.

So we have **one object** of `foo` and we have references to that object as below :

1. `this` (from within instance methods of `foo`)
2. we have instance vatiable `i`
3. and we have variable `x` as reference to that Object

Also as `i` is of type `foo` so it can refer to an object of type `foo` and `this` is also a reference of type `foo` referring to an object of type `foo`. Making `i` equal to `this` makes `i` also referring to same object.

Hope this helps in clearing your doubts.

Comment: Thanks, this helps :)

Comment: you are most welcome

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Java are like pointers, they are not actually the object, but point to the storage where the object is saved. So you create a pointer, pointing to your own object.